# Relation between historical volatility and ATR?

Tags: volatility, algorithmic-trading

https://help.tc2000.com/m/69445/l/754439-historical-volatility-ratio

"Historical volatility is calculated by taking the standard deviation of the natural log of the ratio of consecutive closing prices over time."

https://www.thebalance.com/how-average-true-range-atr-can-improve-trading-4154923

ATR is defined above.

I think there should be a rough relation between the two (for example, they may be roughly different by a factor). But I don't find a thorough comparison between the two.

Could anybody provide a detailed comparison between the two on how they are related to each other?

Comment: Assuming they are both computed over the same period (eg last 60 days of daily data) then they both measure volatility (in different ways) so there may well be a rough proportionality between them. But there is no exact mathematical relationship. It depends among other things on the distribution of returns that you assume or that your data exhibits.

Comment: I would expect a closer relationship between a vol measure using the range (e.g. Parkinson or Garman-Klass) and ATR than between standard close-to-close vol and ATR.

Comment: Note also that the ATR is usually expressed in points eg "as of 2022/03/18 the ATR50 for S&P futures was 108 S&P points" while a close to close vol is most commonly expressed in relative or percentage terms eg "0.0141 or 1.41 % per day c2c vol over last 50 days", with S&P at 4463 that's approx 63 S&P points. You could easily run some tests with variouos estimators (ATR, Parkinson, c2c) along the lines that user42108 suggested and compare the results.